# MS Office Always Open - 2010

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office-2016

I have MS Office 2010 and 2016 installed on my PC.

How can I make sure that MS files are always open in MS 2010 version?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but I haven't tested it myself as I don't have both versions installed:

For each MS office app extension (.docx, .xlsx, .ppt, etc):

Right Click on a file > Open With > Choose another app

Then Select corresponding MS 2010 app (you may need to click on "More apps" to show up) and mark the checkbox "Always use this app to open .docx/.xlsx/.ppt files".

Then click on "OK". The next time you double click on a file with that extension it should open the correct app. Rinse and repeat for each file type.